# Can't get fullpath from fileUpload control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-behind

I have a fileUpload and hidden field at aspx file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuID" runat="server" ToolTip="Select Only Excel File"  />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUl" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('myHiddenInput').value =
document.getElementById('fuID').value" OnClick="btnUlClick" Text="Upload" />

<asp:HiddenField id="myHiddenInput" runat="server" />
```

When I use this code for get fullpath:

```
string abc = myHiddenInput.Value;//Show fullpath
string filepath =null;
if(fuID.HasFile)
filepath = fuID.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();//Show fullpath
```

All of these code show fullPath when I use IE.But when I use FF,It didn't show fullPath,Just show FileName from FileUpload.Anybody help me?Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fuID.PostedFile.FileName);
fuID.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/"+filename));
string filepath = "Files/"+filename;
```

Comment: So that,filename is name of file in fileUPload control.But I don't know why we use fuID.SaveAs(Server.MapPath ("Files...Because we can't know about folder which we choice.We can't set it same hard code.It flexible.It's optional